# How to check if AD user has direct reports

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to check if an AD-User has direct reports (meaning, if that AD-User is a manager), with following code but no go, Any help?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Set-Location AD:

$SamAccountName = "Mansings"

$test = Get-Aduser -identity $SamAccountName -Properties directreports | %{$_.directreports}
Write-Host $test 

if ($test -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "He is a Manager"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "He is not a manager"
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in `$test`?

Comment: $test get values of employees in below format 
CN=User1,OU=Test_Ops,OU=CS Users,DC=EVAL,DC=LOCAL CN=User2,OU=Test_Ops,OU=CS Users,DC=EVAL,DC=LOCAL
Where user1 and 2 reports to Mansing. So I am looking for a condition to check if Mansing is a manager or not.

Answer (score 0):

Got the working script now

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-Location AD:

$SamAccountName = "Mansings"

$test = Get-Aduser -identity $SamAccountName -Properties directreports | %{$_.directreports}
Write-Host $test

if (!$test) 
{
    Write-Host "He is an employee"
 }
 else
 {
    Write-Host "He is a Lead"
}

it's working. Thank you.